# express 4 , app.get with parameters don't work

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my express configuration for static files and views.

```
    express.static.mime.define({'Image': ['png']});
```

Configuration for static files.

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(rootPath, 'app')));
```

Configuration for views

```
   app.set('views', rootPath + '/app/views'); 
   app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
   app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

When I use route without parameters , it works fine , In browser it  create `app` folder and `script` sub-folder and looks for static file in     it, as configured

```
    app.get('/verify',  function(req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    });
```

But when I use route with parameters , In browser it create a   verify folder and look for static file in it

```
   app.get('/verify/:token', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });
```

Please help me here, I am not able to understand where I am making mistake. Why it is creating a verify folder in the browser and looks for static files in it?

Comment: var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../..'); and I guess it is correct as per my folder structure as app.get without parameters renders correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/verify/:token', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

You can't use parameter like this, when you are sending the parameter from verify.jade and you have to use inside app.get, just use req.query.token .

Comment: I am not sending parameter , I am trying to render html page.

Comment: Why are you using token?

Comment: I have not written the complete code over here , I am using token for some verification

Comment: Ok, then you need the token inside app.get, right??